# window.onload not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I use the following JavaScript to set one of my page as a home page when opening the broswer:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        Home(event, 'Home');
    }
</script>
```

here's how the Home function work:

```
function Home(evt, sectionName) {
    var i, tab, tablinks;
    tab = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for (i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
        tab[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; ++i) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

and the CSS:

```
tab {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-top: none;
}
```

They work great on both Chrome and Edge, but not displaying the home page when testing it on Firefox, I tried to create another css class for Home only but using `display: inline` on it, but this will make the home page always stay on the top and appear on every page. I wonder why it is not working properly on Firefox ? and is it possible to fix it ?

Comment: simply add with `<body onload="yourfunction()">`.Its act like window.onload

Comment: or `document.body.onload` instead of `window.onload`

Comment: @prasad That's really simple and work, Thank you! May I ask why would this happen ? and is it bad to use `window.onload` to set a home page ?

Comment: @SteevePitis It works great as well, thank you.

Comment: @Phantom https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add in your js**

```
    var some = function () {
        Home(event, 'Home');
    }
```

**Html**

```html
<body onload="some()">
  <!---your code--->
  </body>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.